# Prove a binomial coefficient identity.

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{p}{k}\binom{q}{k}\binom{n+k}{p+q}} = \binom{n}{p}\binom{n}{q} $$

My try was to use multivariable generating functions(I don't know, I just thought). I hope that there is a solution using combinatorical analogy.